# Deduce that: $\frac{d}{dx}(u^{m}v^{n})=u^{m-1}v^{n-1}[mv\frac{du}{dx}+nu\frac{dv}{dx}]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Deduce that: $$\frac{d}{dx}(u^{m}v^{n})=u^{m-1}v^{n-1}(mv\frac{du}{dx}+nu\frac{dv}{dx})$$

When I differentiate $\frac{d}{dx}(u^{m}v^{n})$ I get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(u^{m}v^{n})=u^{m-1}v^{n-1}(mv+nu)$$
Is : $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $u^m=mu^{m-1}\frac{du}{dx},v^n=nv^{n-1}\frac{dv}{dx}$ now use product rule to get the result

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, logarithmic differentiation is useful and makes life simpler.

Consider $$y=u^m\,v^n$$ where $u,v$ are functions of $x$. Take logarithms $$\log(y)=m \log(u)+n\log(v)$$ Differentiate $$\frac{y'}y=m\frac{u'}u+n\frac{v'}v=\frac{mu'v+nuv'}{uv}$$ Multiply each side by $y$ $$y'=\frac{mu'v+nuv'}{uv} u^mv^n=(mu'v+nuv')u^{m-1}v^{n-1}$$